# Running through all rows in cursor even if there are errors

Tags: sql, transactions, cursor, try-catch, delete-row

I am trying to delete two Ids from a table, in which id '1'  can't be deleted as there is another table referring to Users table but id '2' can be deleted so I want that even if it will give me runtime error for id '1'  , it should run successfully for '2', deleting id '2' from table

But with this code I am getting this error

Msg 3998, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Uncommittable transaction is detected at the end of the batch. The transaction is rolled back.
DECLARE @Id int
DECLARE TempCursor CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR
SELECT ID FROM Users
WHERE Id IN (1,2)

```
                           OPEN TempCursor 
                           
                           WHILE 1=1
                           BEGIN

                           FETCH NEXT FROM TempCursor 
                           INTO @Id
                        
                          
                                          IF @@FETCH_STATUS < 0 BREAK
                                          BEGIN TRY
                                          SET XACT_ABORT ON
                                          BEGIN TRAN DeleteTrans

                                                                    
                                           DELETE Users WHERE Id = @Id             
          


            COMMIT TRAN DeleteTrans
            END TRY

            BEGIN CATCH
            print @AdviserBusinessId

            END CATCH
            
            
            END


           CLOSE TempCursor ;
           DEALLOCATE TempCursor ;
```

Comment: Why would you be using a cursor for this operation?

Comment: @GordonLinoff becuase i have a list of 1000 such ids to delete, so is there any other better way u suggest, thanks

Comment: Why not just something like  `DELETE FROM USERS WHERE <conditions you were going to use on cursor> AND id not in (SELECT id from <other table>)`  ?

Comment: because i will be having multiple tables to delete, there will be tables which will be referring to users table so i will need to delete rows in those tables also